# Switch between classes / jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a login form with some input methods like drop downs, blank fields. My client needs a feature that select yes or no switch like this.

[image]

So I used jQuery add/remove functions when click.

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="member" class="col-md-5 col-sm-12 control-label">
    Do you have the car right now?
  </label>
  <div class="col-lg-10">
    <div class="btn-group">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-switch switch1 active"> <span class="goods">Yes</span>
      </button>
      <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-switch switch1"><span class="services">No</span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.switch1.active{
  background: #e46a5d!important;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-shadow: none;
}
```

Here is a working link for [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jayD2/jkLank8b/1/) But my problem is..

**In some pages, I need to add more yes or no fields like 5 or 6. So I need to repeat jquery script more time.**

So looking for a best practice to do in this kind of situation.

Comment: try this https://jsfiddle.net/aeyn9x29/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without changing your html structure you could simply replace your JS with this;

```
   $('.btn-switch').click(function() {
     var $group = $(this).closest('.form-group');
     $('.btn-switch', $group).removeClass("active");
     $(this).addClass("active");
   });
```

Comment: Thanks! I need to show another options when click yes or no. I hope to use jQuery toggle. So this script won't effect that right?

Comment: No i wouldn't think so. It does exactly what your script was doing except it applies only to the buttons within that form-group.

Answer (score 3):

You should wrap the button in same parent, as I think there is no benefit wrapping *No* button in another `.btn-group`

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-switch active"> <span class="goods">Yes</span>
  </button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-switch"><span class="services">No</span>
  </button>
</div>
```

Use a common class to attach the event handler i.e. `.btn-switch`, then use DOM relationship to remove the classes with the parent DOM structure.

```
 $(document).on("click", ".btn-switch", function() {
   var btnGroup = $(this).closest('.btn-group');
   btnGroup.find(".active").removeClass("active");

   //$(this).siblings(".active").removeClass("active");

   $(this).addClass("active");
 });
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y6x4f2t6/1/)

References

1. [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)
2. [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/)
3. [`.siblings()`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/)

```js
$(document).on("click", ".btn-switch", function() {
  var btnGroup = $(this).closest('.btn-group');
  btnGroup.find(".active").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

```css
.btn-switch.active {
  background: #e46a5d!important;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="member" class="col-md-5 col-sm-12 control-label">
    Do you have the car right now?
  </label>
  <div class="col-lg-10">
    <div class="btn-group">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-switch active"> <span class="goods">Yes</span>
      </button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-switch"><span class="services">No</span>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="member" class="col-md-5 col-sm-12 control-label">
    Do you have the car right now?
  </label>
  <div class="col-lg-10">
    <div class="btn-group">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-switch active"> <span class="goods">Yes</span>
      </button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-switch"><span class="services">No</span>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="member" class="col-md-5 col-sm-12 control-label">
    Do you have the car right now?
  </label>
  <div class="col-lg-10">
    <div class="btn-group">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-switch active"> <span class="goods">Yes</span>
      </button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-switch"><span class="services">No</span>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```